# Running multiple classes wtih Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, testng

Okay, so I am new to Selenium and Java and have been working with automated testing with Selenium in Java for a few weeks and what I want to do is have a class which is called Login which invokes Chrome and have multiple classes with different tests but not in one file. What I want to know is - is it possible to have a package with for example 10 class files with one class which calls them all as separate tests and not have all the tests in one long class file. I have already read some things, but I still can't understand if this is possible with TestNG. I have created a Login class which calls another one, but I can't put a third one and have it called as well. Or is it possible to have one class which calls another class and that class calls another one etc. I am sorry if this question is already asked and answered but I personally couldn't find relevant info on it. I can provide code if necessary.

So I think I asked my question badly and will try to explain a bit better: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/64MY7.jpg
The circled classes include - Login, AppPublisher, SuperadminDelete
I want to run Login and Login to run SuperadminDelete and then AppPublisher
This can easily be done in one class with @Test annotation, but I want them to be separate classes and to be ran by one (let's call it boss or major class). The whole point is each test case to be in a separate class file and not be done with annotation in one file. I guess it is done by the keyword "extends" but when I try it runs only 2 and not all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Please look at my revised answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you mean is to separate 'test case' class from 'test' class,
where the 'test case' would take care of prerequisites workaround such as configurations, login, etc.

I have a basic example in my github project where I use TestNG, Selenium and test case class. Maybe it would help you: https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/selenium-java-pom-example

Regarding your posted code, please separate between loginTest and LoginHelper. loginTest is a method which allows you to test some login scenario to your system. LoginHelper should be a separate class which you should create, that will contain login methods which would be usable by any of your tests. Something like:

```
@Test
void someTest() {

  // Create instance of LoginHelper.
  LoginHelper loginHelper = new LoginHelper(driver);

  // Login to your application.
  loginHelper.loginAsUser();

  // Do the rest of the test here.
}
```

And in that way, your login test would look like:

```
@Test
void loginTest() {

  // Create instance of LoginHelper.
  LoginHelper loginHelper = new LoginHelper(driver);

  // Login to your application.
  loginHelper.loginAssertUser();
}
```